# Filing region between plots with ListLinePlot?

Tags: filling

I have the following plot, where {vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll} are already given in some array and are irrelevant here. I am trying to fill the region between the yellow and red light using the command, Filling -> {2->{3}} but it does not works. What am I missing here? Here is my snippet. Thank you in advance

```
ListLinePlot[{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{0.01, 0.4}, {0, 2}}, 
PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Saphire", Red}, 
Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: While `{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll}` are probably irrelevant here, from a problem-solving-strategy point of view, such assumptions are sometimes the reason problems don't get solved.  For instance, this works for me: `ListLinePlot[Table[Log[x] + k, {k, 3}, {x, 10}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Saphire", Red}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 2 -> {3}}]`

Comment: Well, what I meant was that the data comes from some numerical solutions and it was already organized in tables, so there was no need to show that here. As @kglr showed, the problem is fixed by using Join[decAll, Reverse@pdivAll]. Thanks

Comment: He also showed he needed equivalent data to figure it out. Not everyone would go to the trouble of constructing data you could have supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compressed = "1:eJzV3VFoVmUYB/\
CzTdtsrVxrLTPZVk5dM5eNESKyCwkRClMvRIYXy1RGmYRGSBci4oWIGIhIF+\
I3diESXoiIFyKyi6joIqK6iIguJKKLiOgiIoJ2nlD6juf891/f/5V/N8L6Pn+u533Oec/\
7nvd93v7XDmzb25Jl2cEFs3+8PHnw0N6DTf/+qTm756e22T+2TRyaPPDWxJuTXbM/TL46+\
0fJZzP5Z6/f/ew/Ks/nny1hlFv5N/ta7JVbdFweqP/3bJVovwcZZQbExUm5ScdlIv/m+\
032yjCduyvzb9bKW9pJuUHHZW3+zU/\
8lYH8s8cY5SOQu07KGrqld4PcdVKu0y39MYiLkzKef/YCozTl31xQnrtOyjU6Lp+\
CuDgpi/LPFjLKHpC7TspOuqU/A3FxUq7QLT2SVfcBTsrqjL1jDmbV/\
bSTsoNu6X0gd52Uy3RLfw5y10kZolu6oz6Ctkpnxo5JvgBxcVKepePSnVWP7Z2Ui3Tufgn\
i4qT0Z+wT/\
GhW3Qc4KdN0XL4GcXFSpmjljay6D3BSLtBK3Ftr5S3tpJynlaX137RVeumr8RuQu07Kioz\
tA/aD3HVSztIt/S2Ii5OyjG7p9vybq8pz10lpzdiR8HcgLk7K+\
owdk2gUFF2N8jaduxoFXQEaJe7s1P1Fo6C7lEbppq9GjYJ6Eo0yQueuRkG9vUbZTeeuRkF\
PZBpl4j4r6KlZowzTLa1R0MhGo/Rk7P1Fo6DRp0aJ2XNq/kWjoBkCjfI4HReNgmZxNMoO+\
mrUKGimTaPErB/Vq2mUOWdDG1a203HRKGjGWqMM1v+eyRX0VkGj5H+\
NG5NoFPTmR6NsoVtao6C3cxrllfusoDeoGiVWgFF9gEZBb7k1ygB9NWoUtBJBo2ymW1qjo\
NUiGuVRuqU1ClrRo1E20XHRKGjVlUZ56T4raGWcRumkW1qjoNWLGmUjHReNglaYapR490n\
dMTUKWgWsUeKJmnqC1yhopbZGWUznrkZBq+\
k1yhiduxoF7XjQKL107moUtCtFo2yg46JRboK4aJR8LxE3ytIoMctY0QdolPV0XDTKDRAX\
jbKMzl2Nsiur7gM0yjo6LholxkC18pbWKA9nbB+gUXrqf+\
sESrxdpfppjTIOWlqjLKVzV6NcA1ejRhmlc1ejxPuHVeUtrVE66NzVKFdBXDTKCB0XjXIl\
uRLzIc33T2mvv1YSKGvpuGiUWPvTl1J5iM5djXIZtLRGGabjolFiDUHF06FG6anPpeRKzP\
dUjEk0StyTqX5ao1wCLa1R2unc1SgXkytDdO5qlHjXWvEspVG66dzVKIPgatQog3RcNMo0\
aGmNkv8XbmyvUaaSKyvpuGiUC8mVLjp3Ncr55MoAHReNErOMtfKrUaNEr0b1ARol3vCjfe\
UNK/H8SfXTGqWrvh0SKJ107mqUmDddnFLpp3NXo8S1UtGraZQ2Onc1ymaQuxqll46LRjmd\
Vd8xNUrkErXaVaOcSq4so+\
OiUU4mV1rp3NUoJ5Irhd0QyZWN4GrUKIX1tMmVuENX3DE1SmFFVnLlKGhpjVJ4p59cOZJc\
KbwVSq70gpbWKIW53+TKYRAXjdJNx0WjxPtwNP/\
SsBJXIzW21yiRWbXyltYohTFCcqW1PrMSKIvo3NUo+0HuapROOi4aZRTkrkbJ/\
9o89s41rOwDcdEo8QRPje01yu7kSuHqSK601LdDAqWDzl2NEndM9KTasFL4PZMr7fW/\
dQKl8FlypRvERaNEP02N7TVK4ZsJlEV0XDRKF4iLRmmmc1ejFH7rBEorHReNEmN71Ac0rM\
T9hZ9naFgZS67E1UH10xol5uTQmESjULmrUUbnikvDSguduxqlkFkJlCY6dzVK91wtrVH4\
frphZWCurJufMpnlX//q3q/PdYvLu6F//jL99cbvzg0rHU2KnmJOhXrKmfP/yETh6y+\
0g7g4KXytmePgmnVSnsjm1d/UylvaSdlDX42Ft+a2yiidu60gd52U/\
XRcjoHcdVL4qogLQVyclGX01RizQqvKc9dJ4WtxtoC4OCmH6ZY+\
CnLXSXmPVppAXJyUMbql2+qz3Fbpo6/G2FtV81firkE9Sx0BueukHKNz96+\
sOnedlOO0ElleMSZxUmIlEzV79SeIi5Nygo5LvgSgak2skxIVjqg75h8gLk4KX2O9sGLVV\
jlFt/TvIC5OymlaiWeUij7ASVmesf107PWtlbe0k8KfvhBVaSr6ACcl1sBT95ffQO46KQN\
0Sx8Gueuk8KeY/Ari4qTE+5pmRinsN7BVztFx+QXExUn5gFbeBbnrpMS+Oer+\
8jOIi5PCn0EVc08VfYCTEjt4qTtm1J6o+Sv8yWfvgNx1UrbQufsTyF0nhT9vr7BbzFbJf+\
BGWT+CuDgpU3RcYgVpRU0VJ2Urnbs/gLg4KdN0XKLaYEUf4KTEGgKqD7gN4uKkxFtnqp+\
Od4qoHrOJsp3O3Vg/0Vfe0k4Kf45yYa+vrcKfdf09yF0n5RIdlwMgd50U/oR1dIamk/\
IhHRd0hqaTMkTnLjpx0km5TMcFnTjppMTJZw2fW+\
mkxJ19AaOgEyedlNV07qITJ52UK3TuohMnnZSddO6i8xmdlKt0XND5jE5KPMVSY3t0PqOT\
co2OCzqf0UkZp3MXnc/opFyn44JOM3RS1mRsH4BOM3RS4t0nNbZHpxk6Kbvo3EWnGTopN+\
jcLVR3slWG6dxFZ/\
85KTfpuOwGLe2kxM50amyPzv5zUm7RcUEn5TkpM3eVfE9PQQHmhjur4rntnne/\
XvIZf8TSGPgfcVI20k1zHlw+TkosiaEG4+tASzspW+d3+\
VRMmDgpQ3Tuvgji4qSM03GJRSkVQ1cnZZiOyyiIi5OyllZiKVTFIMJJ4Tf2joC4OClPZuw\
DaizAq+gDnBR+q3Isiq6Vt7STspSOS+\
GoCFslXm9Rj9zDIHedlKfouJwDueukrKNz9zkQFyeF304ez5Ft5bnrpPDbyYckm9LTK7F4\
m+rVzoLcdVL4DfKDki3/6ZUNdEsXDvqxVXrpqzGyvOavxOZWaiR8BuSuk8IXMRiQlGVIr/\
TRLR3b4irGJE7K0Yy9vzwD4uKk8GUZokevGNs7KXxZhn4QFyeln87dwjFttgpfaKIXxMVJ\
iblm6o4ZG8/\
RjLWJwpfOiNFLrbylnZSn6dzdlFX3AU4KXwxkKchdJ4UvBnIK5K6TcpKOyxIQFyeFL29SO\
GTTVuHLm/SAuDgpm+jcPQly10nhC7Z0g7g4Kcsztg+IO1FFH+Ck8AVbYla6z1/\
hC7Z0gpZ2Us7QuVs4UNhW4UvQPALi4qTwJWjiybhiJOykxCx/M6OgYvJOCl+\
CBpVed1JW0LmLSq87KXxRHVR63Unhi+r01/97tgpfVOcYaGknhS+\
qgwqVOyl8UR1UqNxJ4YvqHAUt7aTwRXVQWW8nJf+BG9u31We5rTJFxwUVwXZS+\
KI6qAi2kzJNxwUVwXZS+KI6qGS0kxLPE1Q/\
jUpGOyl8UR1UMtpJ4YvqoALLTgpfVAcVWHZS+KI6qByxk8IX1UHliJ0UvqhOS/2/\
Z6vwRXVQ8V4nhS+qg4r3Oil8UR1U6tZJ4YvqoFK3TgpfVAcVhnVS+\
KI6qDCsk8IX1UFlVJ0UvqgOKqPqpPBFdW7/TxS+\
qA4qOuqk8EV1UIlOJ4UvqoNKdDopfFEdVNDSSeGL6qCClk4KX1QHFbR0UviiOqigpZPCF9\
VB5R+dFL6oDir/6KTwRXXibW7FmMRJ4YvqoPKPTsrMHeVvgxXDlA==";
```

Uncompress to get the three lists:

```
{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll} = Uncompress[compressed];
```

Replicate the issue:

```
ListLinePlot[{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll}, 
 Frame -> True, Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0.01, .4}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Spahire", Red}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Several ways to fix:

**1.** Combine the second and third lists as `Join[decAll, Reverse@pdivAll]` and use it as the fourth input list and add `4 -> Bottom` to the `Filling` option setting:

```
ListLinePlot[{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll, Join[decAll, Reverse@pdivAll]}, 
 Frame -> True, Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0.01, .4}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Spahire", Red, LineOpacity -> 0}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 4 -> {Bottom, LightGreen}}]
```

[image]

**2.** Construct a `FilledCurve` or `Polygon` using `decAll` and `Reverse @ pdivAll`:

```
ListLinePlot[{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll}, 
 Frame -> True, Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0.01, .4}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Spahire", Red}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 2 -> {3}}, 
 Epilog -> {LightOrange, FilledCurve[Line /@ {decAll, Reverse@pdivAll}]}]
```

[image]

Using

```
Epilog -> {LightOrange, Polygon[Join[decAll, Reverse@pdivAll]]}
```

gives the same picture.

**3.** An alternative approach is to create [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html)s from `decAll` and  `pdivAll` and plot them using `ParametricPlot`:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[{vsoundAll, decAll, pdivAll}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.01, .4}, {0, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {"DarkColor", "Spahire", Red}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> Top, 3 -> Top, 3 -> {2}}], 
 ParametricPlot[v BSplineFunction[decAll][t] +
   (1 - v) BSplineFunction[pdivAll][t], 
  {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Number 1 fix worked great ;-). I have to admit that I would not think about Join[decAll, Reverse@pdivAll], did not see any of this in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need? I made up some data because you did not specify.

```
dat1 = Table[{x, 1 - 2 x^2}, {x, 0, 1, .1}];
dat2 = Table[{x, (1 - 10 x^2)}, {x, 0, 1, .1}];
ListLinePlot[{dat1, dat2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Yellow}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, but for some reason it is not working for me. The data I have come from some numerical solutions and it's a bit long table, so that's why I did not post it. Thanks ayways

Comment: You are welcome. You could still thin out your data and post it.